# Thompson Reuters TRBC and GICS

Tags: reuters

I can retrieve the components But I would like 2 retrieve the Index RIC by the sector scheme Code for Both GCIS and TRBC. I would really like 2 get my hands on the components for the Dow Jones sectors / ICB I have them for NYSE but would like the other exchanges. :)
This Finds the Components

```
=RSearch("EQUITY",A2:B5,"NBROWS:2000",,C2)  
RCSIssuerCountryGenealogy   'M:A9/G:6J' 
PriceClose  >5.00
GicsName    'Financials'
IsPrimaryRIC    Yes
Row 1262
```

This Finds the Sector Scheme and code for groupings

```
=TR(OFFSET($C2,0,0,B6,1),"TR.GICSSector; TR.GICSSectorCode;
    TR.GICSIndustryGroup; TR.GICSIndustryGroupCode; TR.GICSIndustry; 
    TR.GICSIndustryCode; TR.GICSSubIndustry; TR.GICSSubIndustryCode
    ","CH=Fd RH=IN",E1)
```

The problem is how do U retrieve the index ric for GICSIndustryGroupCode or GICSIndustryGroup

I found a list of the GCIS symbols broken down by Sectors, Industry Groups, Industries and Sub-Industries But they are EOD symbols :(

Comment: Hi Jeff Crystal, please let [your accounts be merged](http://quant.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can make the edit on your own.